# Why doesn't Resharper's Assembly Explorer show anything?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, explorer

I am trying to decompile an assembly with ReSharper extension for Visual Studio, but when I go to <kbd>ReSharper</kbd>→<kbd>Windows</kbd>→<kbd>Assembly Explorer</kbd>, the explorer is blank. When I have a project open, the tool behaves the way it is meant to, but creating an empty project in order to be able to decompile is just awful. I would like to avoid using the standalone decompiler dotPeek.

Answer (score 2):

The assembly explorer window is intended to show any assemblies that you want to decompile, but aren't referenced in the solution. If an assembly is referenced somewhere in the solution, ReSharper's normal navigation will decompile classes and methods on the fly.

In other words, it's intended to be used in conjunction with the currently open solution, which means it doesn't work without a solution open (also, I believe the list of assemblies in the assembly explorer are stored in the solution settings. Without a solution, there's no list to display).

What's the issue with using dotPeek? It's exactly the same codebase, just compiled with some standalone components rather than as a Visual Studio plugin?

Comment: I wasn't sure it does the exact same, but if it does that's great. Didn't help me solve the problem but answered the question, thank you!